# 'Changes not staged' after git add with nested submodules

Tags: git

I'm attempting to commit and push a Git module which has a series of nested submodules beneath it. After running `git submodule update --remote --recursive`, all of the changes down to the bottom module are updated. But when I attempt to add (`git add -A`) and commit at the top level, I get the message:

```
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   first_submodule (modified content)

no changes added to commit
```

Is there something I need to do apart from `git submodule update --remote --recursive` to refresh the submodules recursively and stage for a commit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the given submodule:

```
cd first_submodule
```

and then figure out what changes you have locally that are not in any commit.  Why do you have these changes that are not in any commit?  (Remember, the submodule *is* a Git repository in its own right.)

The answer to those questions—what's different and not committed, and why is it not committed?—drives the *next* thing you need to do, but until you have those answers, you can't really go on here:

- If the answer turns out to be that there should not be any such changes, you can get rid of them.  This may be simple, or complicated, depending on *why* you have them.
- If the answer turns out to be that the submodule itself needs a new commit, you'll have to make this commit and then get it sent upstream as well, probably.  If you can't get it sent upstream, you might want to make your own fork of whatever project this is instead, and redirect your superproject to this new fork.

Once the submodule itself is back in the proper shape, you will either need to re-add the submodule (to account for the new commit), or there will be nothing left to do and you're already ready to make a new commit in the superproject.